# When going from $(x+2)^2=5$ to $x+2=\pm \sqrt{5}$, why isn't there also a $\pm(x+2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals

Say I am solving the following equation:

$$(x+2)^2 = 5$$

$$x + 2 = \pm \sqrt{5}$$

$$x = -2 \pm \sqrt{5}$$

However, when I took the positive and negative square root of $5$ in the second line, I did not take the positive and negative square root of $(x+2)^2$, which would be $\pm (x+2)$. Why is this?

Comment: Technically, you *could* write $\pm(x+2)=\pm5$. But then that will leave you with these four possibilities: \begin{cases}+(x+2)=+5\implies x+2=5\\+(x+2)=-5\implies x+2=-5\\-(x+2)=+5\implies x+2=-5\\-(x+2)=-5\implies x+2=5.\end{cases} As you can see there are duplicates and it essentially boils down to $x+2=\pm5$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see that when there are like signs, e.g. +(x+2) = +5, the answer is positive and when there are unlike signs (e.g. -(x+2) = + 5, the answer is negative). Since writing x+2 = ±5 satisfies both of these answers, writing ±(x+2) = ±5 is superfluous.

Comment: Yes you got it :) As a tip, it would be great if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (tutorial in link) in posting future questions/answers. Of course, a user has done it for you this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question can be rephrased in abstract form as:

  If we have an equation of the form
  $$a^2=b^2$$
  why is it equivalent to
  $a=\pm b$
  ?
  Why not $\pm a = \pm b$?

As Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer outlined, it can be explained by
\begin{align*}
&a^2=b^2\\[4pt]
\iff\;&a^2-b^2=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&(a-b)(a+b)=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&a-b=0\;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;a+b=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&a=b\;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;a=-b\\[4pt]
\iff\;&a=\pm b\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Thus we have what I'll call the "square-root$\;\pm\;$principle":
$$\boxed{
\;\\[4pt]
\quad a^2=b^2\;\iff\;a=\pm b\quad
\\
}
$$
Applying this principle to the problem at hand, we get
$$(x+2)^2=5\;\iff\;x+2=\pm\sqrt{5}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Better is to write
$$(x+2)^2-\sqrt{5}^2=0$$ and this is, using that $$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$
$$(x+2-\sqrt{5})(x+2+\sqrt{5})=0$$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. Why do you want such a thing to happen ? Cheers

Comment: (-1) Seeing as my previous comment got flagged and removed, I reiterate here. The asker is **not** asking for an alternative way to solve the problem. They are asking **why** taking the square root does not yield plus/minus signs on both sides of the equation. This answer of yours, avoids this, and instead presents a method that the asker does not intend to seek. In the past I have advised you to **fully read** what a post is asking **before** answering, and yet you still continue to do the contrary.

Comment: (+1) Alternate methods are _useful_ to the OP (and others), regardless of whether the OP asked to see alternatives. Moreover, the fact that $a^2=b^2$ is equivalent to $a=\pm b$ is _explained_ by the factorization $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

Comment: @quasi But the OP *isn't* asking for an alternative method. They ask for a justification in one of their steps. [Main point: signs in square root.] [This answer: solves a quadratic evading the signs.]

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Just because the OP doesn't ask for it doesn't mean the OP doesn't benefit from it.

Comment: @quasi Then it would be of benefit for the answerer to *elaborate* on how $a=\pm b$ is explained by $a^2-b^2$; it may be clear to some users like you, but not to others.

Answer (score 2):

When solving $(x+2)^2=5$, recall in general that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. And since  clearly $x+2\in\mathbb{R}$, we have by the last identity that by taking the square root of both sides of $(x+2)^2=5$ $$\sqrt{(x+2)^2}=|x+2|=\sqrt{5}\tag1$$

Then we have reduced the problem to solving $$|x+2|=\sqrt{5}\tag2$$

Recall once more that in general $$|x|=b>0\implies x=b\text{ or }x=-b\tag3$$

Thus putting $(1)$ and $(3)$ together, $$|x+2|=\sqrt{5}\iff x+2=\sqrt{5}\text{ or } x+2=-\sqrt{5}$$

Futhermore, $$x=\sqrt{5}-2\text{ or } x=-\sqrt{5}-2\iff \boxed{x=-2\pm\sqrt{5}}$$